# processing data received from a device

Tags: c#

I have a graphical user interface with 2 buttons (BIT and Data). When I am pressing the BIT button it send a hex data to a port where it is connected a device. The device replay with another hex. I read this hex with port.DataReceived function, display it in a textBox and check each bit from each byte and display value's bit in a textbox. This think is working ok. When I press the Data butoon I send a different hex to the same device and it replay with a defferent hex. Now I just want to display the replay without check it. I have no ideea how I can make it, because when a press the Data button send hex, receive the response from the device and ckeck each bit. I don't want to do this, I just want to display it in a hex. I will post here my code if somebody can help me.

I try to make 2 different function for reading the replay from the device but I think that this way isn't good. I read samething about flags and I hope that is a better way to solve my problem and I wanted to ask for help.

I will post my code here too.

Comment: Off-topic: You might want to think about your use of the word "[hex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hex)"[adecimal]. Remember, you send *bits* to your device, not a hexadecimal number. Hexadecimal is only how those bits are represented to you. Likewise, the device does not answer with a "hex"[adecimal number], but with a collection of bits (grouped into a byte, or a word, or perhaps a sequence of these), which you might then convert into decimal, or hexadecimal, or any other format.

Comment: I totally agree with you stakx. I used a non academical form.Thank you .

Comment: Its always good to post your code if you can. An example of how the two functions work (in terms of receiving and processing the data) would probably make it a lot easier to suggest a course of action.

Comment: Yes Chris I agree with you. I will post it too but now I can't do this because of the terms of the forum.

Answer (score 0):

why not separate out the readFromDevice() code, and pass the received value back to the calling method? That way you could handle the returned values in as many different ways as you like.

Edit:

I'm guessing the devise is going to reply Asynchronously (i.e. it will reply some time after you send it data)? If that's the case, you will need to add an event handler to the com port, then deal with the data you receive.

You will also need to track which button was clicked. You could use a simple boolean value for that:

```
//In the data buttons click handler
DataButtonClicked = true;
BitButtonClicked = false;


//add an event handler to the port
String RecievedData;
SerialPort mySerialPort = new SerialPort("COM1");
mySerialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);

//code for the event handler
private static void DataReceivedHandler(
                    object sender,
                    SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
    RecievedData = sp.ReadExisting();

    if(DataButtonClicked)
    {
         //display the value one way
    }
    if(BitbuttonClicked)
    {
         //display the value another way
    }
}
```

I've based that on the MSDN link I posted below.

Comment: I try to do this but I failed. I will try again with more attention. I realy new in C# and I'm sure that I don't understand very same thinkgs. Thank you for your advice

Comment: can you post your code?

this may be some use: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.datareceived.aspx

Comment: Thank you for your help Jay. This weekend I'm very busy but Monday I will present my code and if I solved the problem or not.

Comment: I finaly posted my code  Jay. Now it do this:0 when I pres the BIT button write to port { 0x10 0x04, 0x06 } and display the same thing in a text box. The device replay, display the response in another text Box, check each value's bite from byte number 7 and display a message in another text box. My problem appear when I press Data button, because I only want to write to port and display in a text Box what it wrote and the response from device. I don't want to check each bit. How I can do this? Can you help me please?

Comment: you just need to add code to track which button was clicked, then in the event handler, call a different method to display the received data based upon which button was clicked.

Answer (score 0):

```
namespace read_display_data
```

{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

```
    SerialPort port = new SerialPort("COM2", 19200, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);


    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();



        port.Open();

    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    port.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(port_DataReceivedBIT);

      // port.ReadTimeout = 500;



    }



    private void BITbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {




            port.Write(new byte[] { 0x10 0x04, 0x06 }, 0, 3);

            byte[] buffer1 = new byte[] {  0x10 0x04, 0x06 };

            LogSent(LogMsgType.Outgoing, DateTime.Now + "  --  " + ByteArrayToHexString(buffer1) + "\n");

            //port.Close();

    }
```

private void Databutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

```
        port.Write(new byte[] { 0x11, 0x43, 0x0D}, 0, 3);


        byte[] buffer1 = new byte[] {0x11, 0x43, 0x0D };

        LogSent(LogMsgType.Outgoing, DateTime.Now + "  --  " + ByteArrayToHexString(buffer1) + "\n");
    }





    private Color[] LogMsgTypeColor = { Color.Blue, Color.Green, Color.Black, Color.Orange, Color.Red };


    public enum LogMsgType { Incoming, Outgoing, Normal, Warning, Error };








    void port_DataReceivedBIT(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {

            //port.Open();

            this.Invoke(new EventHandler(AddReceiveBIT));

    }


    private void AddReceiveBIT ( object s, EventArgs e)
    {


            Thread.Sleep(100);


            byte[] buffer = new byte[port.BytesToRead];

            port.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);


            LogReceive(LogMsgType.Incoming, DateTime.Now + "  --  " + ByteArrayToHexString(buffer) + "\n");


            Log(LogMsgType.Incoming, checkBit(buffer) + "\n");

        }




    private string checkBit(byte[] buffer)
    {
        StringBuilder message = new StringBuilder();
        var responseByte = buffer[7];
        if ((responseByte & (1 << 0)) == 0)
        {
            message.AppendFormat("rezerved                                                                            ok    ");
        }
        else
        {
            message.AppendFormat("rezerved                                                                          error    ");
        }




        if ((responseByte & (1 << 1)) == 0)
        {
            message.AppendFormat("rezerved                                                                            ok   ");
        }
        else
        {
            message.AppendFormat("rezerved                                                                          error   ");
        }



        if ((responseByte & (1 << 2)) == 0)
        {
            message.AppendFormat("rezerved                                                                            ok  ");
        }
        else
        {
            message.AppendFormat("rezerved                                                                          error  ");
        }



        if ((responseByte & (1 << 3)) == 0)
        {
            message.AppendFormat("rezerved                                                                            ok  ");
        }
        else
        {
            message.AppendFormat("rezerved                                                                          error  ");
        }





        if ((responseByte & (1 << 4)) == 0)
        {
            message.AppendFormat("rezerved                                                                            ok  ");
        }
        else
        {
            message.AppendFormat("rezerved                                                                          error  ");
        }





        if ((responseByte & (1 << 5)) == 0)
        {
            message.AppendFormat("rezerved                                                                            ok  ");
        }
        else
        {
            message.AppendFormat("rezerved                                                                          error  ");
        }




        if ((responseByte & (1 << 6)) == 0)
        {
            message.AppendFormat("Serial Communication                                                        ok  ");
        }
        else
        {
            message.AppendFormat("Serial Communication                                                              error  ");
        }





        if ((responseByte & (1 << 7)) == 0)
        {
            message.AppendFormat("Optical Zoom                                                                     ok ");
        }
        else
        {
            message.AppendFormat("Optical Zoom                                                                     error  ");
        }

        return message.ToString();
    }



    private string ByteArrayToHexString(byte[] PortBuffer)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(PortBuffer.Length * 3);
        foreach (byte b in PortBuffer)
            sb.Append(Convert.ToString(b, 16).PadLeft(2, '0').PadRight(3, ' '));
        return sb.ToString().ToUpper();


    }




    private void LogReceive(LogMsgType msgtype, string msg)
    {
        richTextBox1.Invoke(new EventHandler(delegate
        {
            richTextBox1.SelectedText = string.Empty;
            richTextBox1.SelectionFont = new Font(richTextBox1.SelectionFont, FontStyle.Bold);
            richTextBox1.SelectionColor = LogMsgTypeColor[(int)msgtype];
            richTextBox1.AppendText(msg);
            richTextBox1.ScrollToCaret();


        }
        ));


    }
    private void LogSent(LogMsgType msgtype, string msg)
    {
        textBox2.Invoke(new EventHandler(delegate
        {
            textBox2.SelectedText = string.Empty;
            textBox2.AppendText(msg);
            textBox2.ScrollToCaret();

        }
        ));


    }


    private void Log(LogMsgType msgtype, string msg)
    {
        textBox3.Invoke(new EventHandler(delegate
        {
            textBox3.Clear();
            textBox3.SelectedText = string.Empty;
            textBox3.AppendText(msg);
            textBox3.ScrollToCaret();


        }
        ));


    }


    private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void label2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void textBox3_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }


    private void textBox4_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void richTextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Comment: There are my code Chris. I posted it here and hope I will solve my problem.